# My convenience init doesn't work in an extension

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I'm refactoring a `UIViewController` to remove the non-UI stuff that shouldn't be in there. I've been watching [Andy Matuschak's great talk about this](https://vimeo.com/140037432#collections%22Andy%20Matuschak's%20great%20talk%20about%20this) and in one example, he's extending `NSPredicate` and moving logic that figures out what the predicate should be from the view controller into it where it will set the `fetchRequest.predicate` with the result.

I'm trying to do the same thing but I'm getting errors in my extension's convenience init:

```
import Foundation

extension NSPredicate { 
    convenience init(forLiftLogFilter) { // it doesn't like this line
        if let logFilter = UserDefaultsManager.sharedInstance.logFilter?.rawValue {
            filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "lift.liftName = [c] %@", logFilter)
        } else {
            filterPredicate = nil
        }  
    }
}
```

And I'll call it from a `UIViewController' like so:

```
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let filterPredicate = NSPredicate.forLiftLogFilter // thinks NSPredicate doesn't have a member named 'forLiftLogFilter'
        reloadData(filterPredicate)

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  }
```

In my case, I don't need to pass in any initialization parameters but I'm pretty sure I need an external name which is `forLiftLogFilter` so I can make the call. Xcode (8.0/Swift 2.3) is telling me 'Unnamed parameters must be written with the empty name '_'. I understand that error, but I don't actually have any parameters. It must be thinking `forLiftLogFilter` is a parameter or something. And of course since this isn't working, in my `UIViewController` where I'm making the call tells me that 'Type NSPredicate has no member 'forLiftLogFilter'.

I did a lot of reading about extensions, initializers, etc but no answer about a convenience initializer with a name but no parameters.

Can anyone help me understand what's wrong with my initializer?

**For comparison, here's the code Andy uses in his demo**:

```
extension NSPredicate {
    convenience init(forTasksWithinNumberOfDays numberOfDays: Int, ofDate: Date, calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()) {
    self.init(format: "dueDate = %@" argumentArray: [calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.day, value: numberOfDays, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions())!] 
  }
}
```

and he calls it like from view controller like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(forTasksWithinNumberOfDays: 10, ofDate: NSDate())
```

I've added this to show what kind of structure I think I need to be following...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to create a class method that returns an instance of an `NSPredicate`.

Your extension would need to be something like this:

```
import Foundation

extension NSPredicate { 
    static func forLiftLogFilter() -> NSPredicate? {
        if let logFilter = UserDefaultsManager.sharedInstance.logFilter?.rawValue {
            return NSPredicate(format: "lift.liftName = [c] %@", logFilter)
        } else {
            return nil
        }  
    }
}
```

Now you can properly call this class method:

```
let filterPredicate = NSPredicate.forLiftLogFilter
```

Comment: Hi @rmaddy, I don't think that's what I'm trying to do, but then again, I'm kind of a newbie so I don't necessarily know what I'm talking about. I added an example of the code that I'm trying to approximate. Maybe that will clear it up. Does the `self.init()` possibly make a difference?

Comment: Also, Andy makes a comment when he shows that extension and says, "I could have just as easily made some kind of factory type, that would be equivalent." Is that at all similar to what you suggested?

Comment: You can't use the same approach because you don't have any parameters to pass to the `init` method to distinguish it from other `init` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a convenience initializer.

Just call

```
    var filterPredicate: NSPredicate = nil
    if let logFilter = UserDefaultsManager.sharedInstance.logFilter?.rawValue {
            filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "lift.liftName = [c] %@", logFilter)
    }
```

whenever you need it.

Or if you want it for use in a class-scope:

```
private lazy var filterPredicate: NSPredicate = {
    if let logFilter = UserDefaultsManager.sharedInstance.logFilter?.rawValue {
        return NSPredicate(format: "lift.liftName = [c] %@", logFilter)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to work since there is no class named `forLiftLogFilter`. That is simply a name the OP wanted to use for the method.

Comment: Also note that a convenience init method must call a designated init. This implementation does not do that.

Comment: Your edit still isn't valid. The OP does not have anything at all that needs to be passed to this `init` in the extension.

Comment: Now your answer makes no attempt to answer the question being asked. It may be a valid comment but the OP is asking about a specific error and this updated answer doesn't address the problem at all.

Comment: I'm pointing it out because long ago I posted an answer like this one and I got down voted like crazy for not answering the actual question even though my answer pointed out a better solution. Based on that experience it is always best to answer the actual question, and then if you want, also present an alternative solution.